# select children of the first element of a certain class using XPath

Tags: php, xpath

i have this type of code:

```
<div class="content">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

i wish to select all `p` elements from the first element with the class `content`.
i managed to select the first class by using:

```
(//div[@class="content"])[1]
```

but using `(//div[@class="content"])[1]/p` it still shows both classes

Comment: The XPath you tried should work. How are you executing it?

Comment: I'm using PHP with $content = $xpath->query('(//div[@class="content"])[1]/p');  if i remove the p from xpath i get the right nodes.

Comment: When your question says "does not work", you need to specify: (1) what actually happened (in terms of something observable, like particular output), and (2) what you expected to happen. So far neither has been supplied.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an working example using `PHP's SimpleXML`. I've made some small changes to the `HTML` code you provided so the output would be more meaningful.

<s>Regarding the XPath expression you provided I just removed the parenthesis and it all worked as expected.</s>

***NOTE***: Following @LarsH's comment, I reverted the XPath expression as it was OK for starters. I took the liberty to update it based on its example.

```
<?php
$html = <<<HTML
<body>
    <div class="content">
        <p>1</p>
        <p>2</p>
        <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <p>4</p>
        <p>5</p>
        <p>6</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <div class="content">
            <p>7</p>
            <p>8</p>
            <p>9</p>
       </div>
   </div>
</body>
HTML;

$sxe = new SimpleXMLElement($html);
foreach ($sxe->xpath('(//div[@class="content"])[1]/p') as $p) {
    echo "$p\n";
}
```

#### Output:

```
1
2
3
```

Link to [codepad working example](http://codepad.org/hjVr1gA3).

Comment: You did not mention the changes you made to the XPath, the one crucial part of your answer.

Comment: I added a paragraph to mention the changes to the XPath expression. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @Rolando: your code works for the sample input data, but it isn't equivalent to what the OP asked for. The OP asked for "all p from the first content class", but you're selecting all p from all "content" class divs that are the first child **of their respective parent**. See http://codepad.org/6NB1nRRV to illustrate the difference. Moreover, your XPath expression is no more valid than the OP's, so it doesn't explain why the OP's "doesn't work."

Comment: @LarsH thanks a lot for pointing out the flaws in my answer. Hail to the beauty of SO :)

Comment: Thanks for listening. Hope I didn't come across too harsh. :-)